# Deleting Database data by chosing in combobox and deleting it then with button c#

Tags: c#, mysql

So i want to delete data from MySql by selecting data i want to delete in CombBox and with button Delete i want to delete it so i was thinking if it would work with this code:

```
string Query = "DELETE FROM filmi.film WHERE film='"+this.comboBox2."' ;";
```

but i dont know what to put after `+this.comboBox2.` <- here or is there any other way this could be done?

the whole code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
        string Query = "DELETE FROM filmi.film WHERE film='"+this.comboBox2."' ;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i dont know what to put after +this.comboBox2. <- here

You can use `SelectedItem` property to get the SelectedItem from the `Combobox`.

**Suggestion:** your query is open to `SQL-Injection attacks` , so i'd suggest you to use `Parameterised Queries` to avoid them.

Try This: using `Parameterised Queries`

```
    string Query = "DELETE FROM filmi.film WHERE film=@film;";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@film",this.comboBox2.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: ok works thanks again :) will accept the answer as soon as i can:)

Comment: @user3375194:  you are welcome dear :) , i'm glad tobe help of you again :)

Answer (score 0):

The ComboBox class has members for SelectedItem and SelectedValue.  It depends on what your combobox is populated with, which you haven't specified in your post.  If it's just strings, you could use either.

See the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx